# Why is my program goes straight to else block when it should enter if

Tags: python

I was trying to make a simple survey bot, but I had trouble with the second if statement. it just ignores the if and elif, and goes straight to the else statement. I have tried everything, and even though it's probably going to be an easy solution please help...

```
 import sys

 yes = "yes"
 no = "no"
 experience_good = "yes"
 contact = "1"

 print("How many times have you bean contacted by us in the past quarter (3 months)")
 contact = sys.stdin.readline()

 if contact != 0:
     print("Was your experience was us good? Type a 1 for yes or 0 for no")
     experience_good = sys.stdin.readline()
     print("experiencence_good is", experience_good)
     # The above line was just to double check the variable was inputted 
correctly
     if experience_good is 1:
         print("Good to hear that.")
     elif experience_good is 0:
         print("Sorry about that. What could we be doing better?")
         doing_better = sys.stdin.readline()
     else:
         print("Stuff's been messed up")
```

The output I get is just:

> How many times have you bean contacted by us in the past quarter (3
> months)
>
> 3
>
> Was your experience was us good? Type a 1 for yes or 0 for no
>
> 1
>
> exp_good is 1
>
> Stuff's been messed up

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev and @Emerson SD, you guys made a minor mistake. In the `contact = sys.stdin.readline()` return a string not an integer, then you are checking `contact != 0`. Fix that and it should work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `experience_good` is never `1`! It's starts off as

```
experience_good = "yes"
```

Then halfway through it **maybe** changed as

```
experience_good = sys.stdin.readline()
```

At this point if the user typed in `1`, what the variable will hold is the string value `'1'` which is not `1` so you need to

```
experience_good = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `==` for int equality test:

```
if contact != 0:
    print("Was your experience was us good? Type a 1 for yes or 0 for no")
    experience_good = sys.stdin.readline()
    print("experiencence_good is", experience_good)
    # The above line was just to double check the variable was inputted  correctly
    if experience_good == 1:
        print("Good to hear that.")
    elif experience_good == 0:
        print("Sorry about that. What could we be doing better?")
        doing_better = sys.stdin.readline()
    else:
        print("Stuff's been messed up")
```

Cast the `contact` and `experience_good` to `int`:

```
contact = int(contact)

experience_good = int(experience_good)
```

Answer (score 1):

Indentation problem (now edited in question). Bring the last elif and last else block one indent backwards.

```
if experience_good == 1:
    print("Good to hear that.")
elif experience_good == 0:
    print("Sorry about that. What could we be doing better?")
    doing_better = sys.stdin.readline()
else:
    print("Stuff's been messed up")
```

Use == to evaluate a value. When you use 'is' it will compare the objects. Not it's value.

Comment: Why do you think it's the indentation?

Comment: Indentation was fine in the original revision, and it was not the problem. (it got messed up in subsequent edits)

Comment: Ok. Indentation is fixed. Can you also fix the last line of output: Stuff's been messed up

Comment: And also this post title. @Sergio Tulentsev